# Vue.js built css code is ignored by the components

Tags: vue.js, sass, node-sass, sass-loader

this is my first post here .

I am currently developing a chrome extension with vue thanks to the amazing `vue-cli-plugin-browser-extension` plugin.

Hopefully, I succeeded in adding sass to the project by installing the `node-sass` and `sass-loader` packages and now I am able to use `<style lang="scss">` in my `.vue` components, what is working correctly in development mode (`vue-cli-service build --mode development --watch`).

But once I want to build my application, `vue-cli-service build` command will build the javascript files without error but I will not have the css files built from my scss code.

I tried adding the configuration snippet I've found in the [vue.js documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass) into my `vue.config.js` file but it's still not working and I am facing the error bellow:

```
⠏  Building for production...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 10 errors                                              00:41:57

 error  in ./src/components/Chat.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&

SassError: Invalid CSS after "...load the styles": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"
        on line 1 of src/components/Chat.vue
>> @import "@/assets/main.scss";

   -----------------------------^
```

I have a `main.scss` file which is plain sass code:

```
:root {
    --color-primary: #3ba4fe;
    --color-primary-light: #2e88d6;

    --color-blue-dark-1: #2c2d35;
}
```

Here is my `devDependencies`:

```
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/devtools": "^5.3.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.5",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-browser-extension": "~0.25.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
```

And my `vue.config.js`:

```
...
configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            'vue-style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader'
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: `@import "@/assets/main.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
```

Any help would be pleased, thank you!

Edit: Actually, the css files are built when removing the webpack config (above) but the styling is ignored by the Vue components.

Comment: *I have a main.scss file which is plain sass code* It's not sass, it's css.